# Can You Make A .bat that starts a cmd with any title and color b?

Tags: batch-file, colors, cmd

I Make cmd look cool by putting color in to it and changing the title, I was wondering if i could make a bat that starts cmd with a color and a custom title so I don't need to do it every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the `title` and `color` properties to the current batch file window, then call command prompt:

```
@echo off
title YourTitle
color 0b
call cmd
```

In my example i used 0b which is blue text on a black background, but of course you can change it to [any of these](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntcolor.php).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the following commands:

title [name]

color [attr]

attr values:

```
0 = Black       8 = Gray
1 = Blue        9 = Light Blue
2 = Green       A = Light Green
3 = Aqua        B = Light Aqua
4 = Red         C = Light Red
5 = Purple      D = Light Purple
6 = Yellow      E = Light Yellow
7 = White       F = Bright White
```

then call the command line:

```
call cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your command prompt background color and font using its properties.
Just open a cmd on top left click on the icon and select properties.
You can set it there.

Regarding to the title, I'm not sure it's possible to change to something permanent - but maybe I'm wrong.

Liron